# What are the 101 clans of Yadavas?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, chandravansh, yadavas

[SB 10.90.44](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/90/44):

> tan-nigrahāya hariṇā
>
> proktā devā yadoḥ kule
>
> avatīrṇāḥ kula-śataṁ
>
> teṣām ekādhikaṁ nṛpa
>
> To subdue these demons, Lord Hari told the demigods to descend into the dynasty of Yadu. They comprised **101 clans**, O King.

Does any text provide details of these clans (at least their names)?